# No files under mount point

Tags: linux, mount, tmpfs

I would like to mount my pendrive (`/dev/sdc1`) under `/tmp/my_dir`.
I used the following command:
`sudo mount -t tmpfs /dev/sdc1 /tmp/my_dir`.
I got no errors from `mount` command. When I check all my mounted devices I see: `/dev/sdc1 on /tmp/my_dir type tmpfs (rw,relatime)` but when I use `ls -l /tmp/my_dir` I get `total 0`.

Do you have any idea what can cause the problem? Thank you in advanced for any help.

Comment: From the tmpfs man page: "The tmpfs facility allows the creation of filesystems ***whose contents reside in virtual memory***". It's not a file system that resides on a storage device. I'd say just leave out the `-t` option and let the mount command figure out the filesystem type. I believe your mount command is syntactically correct; the /dev/sdc1 parameter is probably just a dummy.

Comment: @berndbausch Thank you very much. It works.